# All possible combinations (including all subsets combinations) of two or more lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I searched the net but couldn't find anything. I am trying to get all possible combinations including all subsets combinations of two lists (ideally n lists). All combinations should include at least one item from each list.

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = [5,6]

output = [
    [1,5], [1,6], [2,5], [2,6], [3,5], [3,6],
    [1,2,5], [1,2,6], [1,3,5], [1,3,6], [2,3,5], [2,3,6], [1,5,6], [2,5,6], [3,5,6],
    [1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,6], 
    [1,2,3,5,6]
]
```

All I can get is pair combinations like [1,5], [1,6], .. by using

```
combs = list(itertools.combinations(itertools.chain(*ls_filter_columns), cnt))
```

What is the pythonic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def non_empties(items):
    """returns nonempty subsets of list items"""
    subsets = []
    n = len(items)
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        subsets.extend(combinations(items,i))
    return subsets
    
list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = [5,6]

combs = [list(p) + list(q) for p,q in product(non_empties(list_1),non_empties(list_2))]
print(combs)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 5, 6], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 5, 6], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]]
```

Which has more elements then the output you gave, though I suspect that your intended output is in error. Note that my code might not correctly handle the case in which there is a non-empty intersection of the two lists. Then again, it might -- you didn't specify what the intended output should be in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.
Even though it is not fancy, it cares n_lists easily.

```
def change_format(X):
    output = []
    for x in X:
        output += list(x)
    return output

import itertools
list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = [5,6]
list_3 = [7,8]

lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]
lengths = list(map(len, lists))
rs_list = itertools.product(*[list(range(1, l+1)) for l in lengths])

output = []
for rs in rs_list:
    temp = []
    for L, r in zip(lists, rs):
        temp.append(list(itertools.combinations(L, r)))
    
    output += list(itertools.product(*temp))
            
output = list(map(change_format, output))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work for n-lists with less code, which was a challenge for me.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product

def get_subsets(list_of_lists):
    """
    Get all possible combinations of subsets of given lists
    :param list_of_lists: consists of any number of lists with any number of elements
    :return: list
    """
    ls = [chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(e, x), range(1, len(e)+1))) for e in list_of_lists if e]
    ls_output = [[i for tpl in ele for i in tpl] for ele in product(*ls)]
    return ls_output

list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [5, 6]
list_3 = [7, 8]
ls_filter_columns = [list_1, list_2, list_3]
print(get_subsets(ls_filter_columns))
```